# sqlite3 - getting trouble with SQLite3 shell

Tags: sqlite

I am new to SQLite3.

I am trying to create a DB in the shell. When I run the shell,  it already shows:

> SQLite version 3..
>
> Enter ".help" for instructions ..
>
> Enter SQL...
>
> Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"

I read somewhere that I should be able to type "$" and codes like "$ sqlite3 mynotes.db"

Now, I need to be able to name my DB (like "mynotes.db") and be able to decide in which folder I want it to be saved.

Can someone help me? Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` somewhere was supposed to be a prompt of some shell (command processor), where you start `sqlite3` and specify database name (which is created if does not exists).

If you're running `sqlite3` without a shell (by clicking on `sqlite3.exe`?), it's time to try another way. `CMD.EXE` on Windows is as good for this job as a typical Unix shell.

As of the folder where the database will be: either `cd` to this folder before you run `sqlite3 mynotes.db`, or specify full pathname to the database: `sqlite3 "C:\Users\Me\Documents and Settings\mynotes.db"` (double quotes are needed when argument contains spaces).

When `sqlite3` is started with no parameters, the database will be in memory. Sqlite3 supports "attaching" other databases (see [ATTACH DATABASE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) description). This way, you can create and open on-disks databases even if starting `sqlite3` with parameters is impossible for some reason (or too hard).